# Reinforcement learning, how can I get the entropy of an distribution?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I read a paper **Multi-Agent Actor-Critic for Mixed Cooperative-Competitive Environments**, and I found the approximate policy is learned by maximizing
the log probability of agent $j$’s actions, with an entropy regularizer

[image]

In general, what is entropy regularizer in reinforcement learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy of an agent is a (conditional) probability distribution across actions. The entropy of a policy is just the entropy of that distribution. An entropy regularizer encourages more entropy in the policy, which corresponds to more exploration.